# Write 3D data into HDF5 file in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, hdf5

I'm trying to write three-dimensional data ([image: Nx x Ny x Nz]), which are stored in memory like a linear array ([image: k + Nz * j + Nz * Ny * i]), into HDF5 file using hyper slabs. See my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

#include "hdf5.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, k;
    int count = 0;
    int Nx = 180;
    int Ny = 128;
    int Nz = 128;

    double *data = (double *)malloc(Nx * Ny * Nz * sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < Ny; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < Nz; k++)
            {
                data[k + Nz * j + Nz * Ny * i] = (double)count;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    hid_t err;
    hid_t dataspace, memspace, dataset;
    hid_t file_identifier;
    int rank;
    hsize_t dimens_3d[3];
    hsize_t start_3d[3];
    hsize_t stride_3d[3];
    hsize_t count_3d[3];

    char *file_name = "data.h5";

    file_identifier = H5Fcreate(file_name, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

    rank = 3;

    dimens_3d[0] = Nz;
    dimens_3d[1] = Ny;
    dimens_3d[2] = Nx;

    dataspace = H5Screate_simple(rank, dimens_3d, NULL);

    start_3d[0] = 0;
    start_3d[1] = 0;
    start_3d[2] = 0;

    stride_3d[0] = 1;
    stride_3d[1] = 1;
    stride_3d[1] = 1;

    count_3d[0] = Nz;
    count_3d[1] = Ny;
    count_3d[2] = Nx;

    err = H5Sselect_hyperslab(dataspace, H5S_SELECT_SET, start_3d, stride_3d, count_3d, NULL);

    dimens_3d[0] = Nz;
    dimens_3d[1] = Ny;
    dimens_3d[2] = Nx;

    memspace = H5Screate_simple(rank, dimens_3d, NULL);

    start_3d[0] = 0;
    start_3d[1] = 0;
    start_3d[2] = 0;

    stride_3d[0] = 1;
    stride_3d[1] = 1;
    stride_3d[1] = 1;

    count_3d[0] = Nz;
    count_3d[1] = Ny;
    count_3d[2] = Nx;

    err = H5Sselect_hyperslab(memspace, H5S_SELECT_SET, start_3d, stride_3d, count_3d, NULL);

    dataset = H5Dcreate(file_identifier, "data", H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, dataspace, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

    err = H5Dwrite(dataset, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, memspace, dataspace, H5P_DEFAULT, &(data[0]));

    H5Sclose(memspace);
    H5Sclose(dataspace);
    H5Dclose(dataset);

    H5Fclose(file_identifier);

    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

This example isn't put any data into the file and I can't figure out why. The file is created but when I dump it into XML file using h5dump utility (h5dump -u data.h5 > data.xml) there are no values for `data` array. If I comment lines with `H5Sselect_hyperslab` function values appear in the file.

I understand that here using of `H5Sselect_hyperslab` function isn't necessary, but the next step for me will be to write HDF5 in parallel where using of hyper slabs would be necessary.

Comment: Please, provide a complete compilable example.

Comment: How do you know tht the fie got opened at all?  Does the file exist?  Does it contain anything?  Where are your details from debugging?  This question is hopeless:((

Comment: I've updated code and extended the problem description. Once again, the file is created and I can see the content of the file using h5dump utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a typo in `stride_3d`: you set `stride_3d[1]` twice and never set `stride_3d[2]` so the initial value of `stride_3d[2]` is undefined (a.k.a. garbage) and the call to `H5Sselect_hyperslab` fails. Which brings us to my second point…

**Check your errors!** You should be checking the value of `err` after every API call.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, it was a silly mistake. Now I'm checking error codes.